# Prove $\frac{1}{n} =\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ for all integers $n\in\Bbb Z$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

I'm pretty sure that we need induction, since it's the format I had to use for previous problems similar to this (it isn't specified that it HAS to be an inductive proof, either, if there is another way I can solve this one.) The base case checks out except for $-1$ and $0$, which leads to $1/0$ at some point in the formula, so I'm excluding those two from $n$. So I assume that $n=k$ holds as well and have to prove for $n=k+1$. I understand the format of an inductive proof.

I'm just not seeing how to manipulate the problem correctly for the induction to work. I've tried multiplying by $\frac{1}{k}$ but that messes up the last part of the equation, leading to $k^3$. Doing the $\gcd$ just makes the numerators messy in a way I can't easily clean up. I'm not sure what algebra I should be using to get the induction I need. What's the format for the solution to this problem?

Comment: Bring the right side to a common denominator. No induction needed.  But result obviously fails at $n=-1$ and, one could perhaps argue, at $n=0$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{n + 1} + \frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{n}{n(n + 1)} + \frac{1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{n + 1}{n(n + 1)} = \frac{1}n
$$

Comment: To be especially clear, there is the expression $ \frac{n}{n(n+1)} + \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ before the first two elements of this equality.

Comment: I would say if the OP is having such problems to note that $\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n}\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n}{n(n+1)}$ and this equality holds because $\frac{n}{n}=1$ for $n\neq 0$ and multiplying by one doesn't change a number. Also the multiplication of fractions is top by top, bottom by bottom which isn't hard to show with a reasonable definition of what a fraction is.

Answer (score 1):

Cut a square into $(n+1)$ pieces, with one piece across the full width (in green), then $n$ pieces in vertical slices  - shown below is the scheme for 7 pieces.

[image]

Then you can see that the light-blue $\frac{1}{n+1}$ slice added to a  $\frac 1n$ portion of the green  $\frac{1}{n+1}$ slice - that is, $\frac{1}{n+1} + \frac 1n\frac{1}{n+1}$ - is a $\frac 1n$ slice of the square.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}+\frac{1}{n+1}=(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1})+\frac{1}{n+1}$.